# Salesforce Button that adds new text fields

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

So I am trying to add a button on Case Object next to Product that will state "Add Product" so whenever it is clicked, it will add a Textfield for a second or third product to be added to a Case. The catch: Product field is a lookup field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is doable and you'll get help.  However I want to extend the caviat that custom buttons are being retired with the roll out of the new Lightning interface.  So you may want to check in and see what the org's timeline is for rolling out Lightnging and/or code to the coming release's limitations.

Here's a good forum thread on the topic: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BWr4IAG

Comment: Is legacy going away all together? My Org does not use Lightening since we are already comfortable with Legacy. That would be unfortunate to have all of my custom links, buttons, layouts I made for each department be gone.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, a lookup field can only reference one object. You could make multiple lookup fields to the same object (i.e. Product_1__c, Product_2__c, etc.) but this can cause you to have a cluttered UI and you don't always know the maximum number of Products you may need to add.

To dynamically add more of these Product fields, you'll need to create an "Assigner" object that sits between your Case and Product Object. So, every time you click the Add button, another "Case-Product Assigner" is created, which has a lookup field to both the Case and Product object.

The visualforce code would look something like:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!AddProductAssigner}" >
        Add Product
</apex:commandLink>
```

With the controller looking like:

```
public void AddProductAssigner(){
    insert new Case_Product_Assigner__c(Case__c = caseId);  
}
```

Comment: Does not work. gives errors trying to create the Apex Class.